# Eclipse shows error after installing color theme

Tags: eclipse

After installing color theme in Eclipse the program no longer starts.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank in advance,
Cheers.

```
!SESSION 2019-01-11 19:11:20.156 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -pluginCustomization C:/intelfpga_lite/18.1/nios2eds/bin/eclipse_nios2/plugin_customization.ini
Command-line arguments:  -data file:/C:/Users/kosti/sbt4e-18.1-workspace/ -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product -pluginCustomization C:/intelfpga_lite/18.1/nios2eds/bin/eclipse_nios2/plugin_customization.ini

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-01-11 19:11:34.429
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.application, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM, org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

Comment: What color theme? What exactly did you do?

Comment: Downloaded a theme from application (i believe it was called "Color Theme").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to set ENV variable because its showing `"org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry.` Try this :

Control Panel → View advanced system settings → Advanced tab → Environment Variables

Now you have to do 2 things:

Create a new variable (click the New button):

Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`

Variable value:`C:\Program Files\Java\[your Java Version]`

Edit the Path variable and add this to the end of that:

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However now i can not access eclipse marketplace. Any ideas why ?

Comment: @JakubKostiw if this answer worked for you, consider accepting it.

Comment: The thing is, that i no longer have a marketplace inside Eclipse :(. I cant not find it in Help ->, nor when i try to find it in "Quick Access".

Comment: @JakubKostiw You are using Eclipse -Oxygen  ?

Comment: I am using Eclipse that comes with Quartus Prime 18.1 (i am using NIOSII).  I believe it is called "Mars.2".